# Passing Mysql query results to javascript and then calling function using original variable.

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I appologize if this is a dumb question but I'm self taught -.-

**Scenario** I have a invoice php, js page that allows for manual entry of line items. I wanted to change out the text area for a drop down list populated by a mysql database that I have filed with items. I am able to get 1 line to pull up in the drop down, but not the array of results.

I am modifying existing code so if you have any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you for the help.

PHP Code mysql query storing results to $description variable.

```
$customerquery="SELECT description FROM es_items";
$customerresults=mysql_query($customerquery) or die ("Query to get data from customer table failed: ".mysql_error());

while ($customerrow=mysql_fetch_array($customerresults)) {
    $description=$customerrow[description];
}
```

PHP js call to add a row

```
<tr id="hiderow">
    <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$("#addrow").click(function(){
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Item Name</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><select name="description"><option>' + description +'</option></select></td><td><textarea class="cost">$0</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">0</textarea></td><td><span class="price">$0</span></td></tr>');
if ($(".delete").length > 0) $(".delete").show();
bind();
```

You can view what it is doing at http://estimate.roedermgt.com

Comment: Please, stop using the `mysql_*` extension. It's now officially _deprecated_. Switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead. just go to any `php.net/mysql_*` page, and read the read box saying _"Warning"_, and click on the links to the suggested alternatives

Comment: `$(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="item-name"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>Item Name</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td><td class="description"><select name="description"><option>' +  description + '</option></select></td><td><textarea class="cost">$' + price + '</textarea></td><td><textarea class="qty">' + 1 + '</textarea></td><td><span class="price">$'+ price +'</span></td></tr>');`

Comment: I think i need to loop through the description, but am unsure how to do it. would assume something like
$(".item-row:last").after( for(x=0; count(description); x++){description} ); but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the value of each row in your while loop, instead of building up a collection. As a result, only one row is being returned.

Try making `$description` an array:

```
while ($customerrow = mysql_fetch_array($customerresults)) {
    $description[] = $customerrow[description];
}
```

Comment: It returns "Array" now with no other results.

Comment: using the above and modifying the php js to  
`<script type="text/javascript">var description = new Array (<?PHP echo json_encode ( $description );?>)</script>`

results in all the data coming through, but it appears in 1 row.....

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not iterating through the list correctly in php it should be

```
$description[] = $customerrow[description];
```

Comment: using the above and modifying the php js to  
`<script type="text/javascript">var description = new Array (<?PHP echo json_encode ( $description );?>)</script>`

results in all the data coming through, but it appears in 1 row.....